# Define number of decimal places that appears in the cbar with seaborn.kdeplot

Tags: python-3.x, seaborn, legend-properties

From the following code:

```
penguins = sns.load_dataset("penguins")
g = sns.PairGrid(penguins)
g.map_upper(sns.histplot,)
g.map_lower(sns.kdeplot, fill=True,cbar=True)
g.map_diag(sns.histplot, kde=True, cbar=True)
```

the legend bar has between 3 and 5 decimal places and I would like it to only have 2. I have tried using the following code but it keeps giving me errors.

```
g.cbar.ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(tick.FormatStrFormatter('%.2f'))
```

The error that occurs is:  'PairGrid' object has no attribute 'cbar'

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an easy way to access the colorbars.  Apart from that, the colorbars aren't showing easily interpretable information; moreover, they overload the visual information. It would be better to leave them out. (`sns.histplot` even doesn't create a colorbar, as it doesn't contain color mapped information.)

Comment: `[ax for ax in g.fig.axes if ax.get_label() == "<colorbar>"]`

Comment: That said I agree that KDE colorbars rarely add value.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
g.map_lower(sns.kdeplot, fill=True,cbar=True,cbar_kws = dict(format = '%.2f'))
g.map_diag(sns.histplot, kde=True, cbar=True,cbar_kws = dict(format = '%.2f'))
```